# Generar objetos de una clase en base a datos de un XML

Tags: java, xml, object

Tengo una carpeta con 5 XML's con descripciones de una serie de vehículos y sus atributos.

Por otro lado, tengo un parser creado que me lee estos XML's y muestra los datos por consola.

Por último tengo creada la clase Vehículo con todos sus getters y setters.

Necesitaría que al leer los XML's, los datos generaran los atributos de los objetos de la clase Vehículo (5 en concreto).
Como puedo hacerlo???

**AQUÍ LA CLASE VEHÍCULO:**

```
`introducir el código aquí`
```

package com.company;

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;



public class Vehiculo {

    // atributos

    private String nombre;
    private String parrafos;
    private Double precio;
    private ImageIO imagen;
    private String web;
    private Integer id;
    private boolean updatable;

    // constructores

    public Vehiculo(){

    }

    public Vehiculo(String nombre, String parrafos, Double precio, ImageIO imagen, String web, Integer id, boolean updatable){
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.parrafos = parrafos;
        this.precio = precio;
        this.imagen = imagen;
        this.web = web;
        this.id = id;
        this.updatable = updatable;
    }


    // getters

    public String getNombre(){
        return nombre;
    }
    public String getParrafos(){
        return parrafos;
    }
    public Double getPrecio () {
        return precio;
    }
    public ImageIO getImagen () {
        return imagen;
    }
    public String getWeb () {
        return web;
    }
    public Integer getId () {
        return id;
    }
    public boolean isUpdatable () {
        return updatable;
    }

    // setters

    public void setNombre(String nombre){
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public void setParrafos ( String parrafos ) {
        this.parrafos = parrafos;
    }
    public void setPrecio ( Double precio ) {
        this.precio = precio;
    }
    public void setImagen ( ImageIO imagen ) {
        this.imagen = imagen;
    }
    public void setWeb ( String web ) {
        this.web = web;
    }
    public void setId ( Integer id ) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public void setUpdatable ( boolean updatable ) {
        this.updatable = updatable;
    }
```

introducir el código aquí

**AQUÍ EL CODIGO CON EL PARSER QUE LEE LA ESTRUCTURA DE LOS ARCHIVOS XML:**

```
package com.company;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Main {



    // private final static String filename = "/Users/manuelmoreno/Desktop/LA SALLE DAW/Docs y entregas/M03-UF5/UF5-PR01-VehicuosRecreativos/catalogo/mercedes.xml";


    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, TransformerException, IOException {

        File dir = new File("/Users/manuelmoreno/Desktop/LA SALLE DAW/Docs y entregas/M03-UF5/UF5-PR01-VehicuosRecreativos/catalogo");
        String[] ficheros = dir.list();

        for(int i=0; i<ficheros.length; i++) {
           // System.out.println(ficheros[i]);
            System.out.println("\n");
            Path path = Paths.get(("/Users/manuelmoreno/Desktop/LA SALLE DAW/Docs y entregas/M03-UF5/UF5-PR01-VehicuosRecreativos/catalogo/")+(ficheros[i]));
            //writeInFile(path);
            readFromFile(path);

        }

    }

    private static void readFromFile(Path path) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document document = builder.parse(path.toFile());

        //Normalize the XML Structure; It's just too important !!
        document.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        //Here comes the root node
        Element root = document.getDocumentElement();

        //Get all data from xml
        NodeList nList = document.getElementsByTagName("camper");

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++)
        {
            Node node = nList.item(temp);
            System.out.println("");
            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
            {
                //Print each vehicle's detail and create object all along

                Element eElement = (Element) node;
                System.out.println("id : "    + eElement.getAttribute("id"));
                System.out.println("Name : "  + eElement.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getTextContent());
                for(int n=0; n<eElement.getElementsByTagName("p").getLength(); n++) {
                    System.out.println("Parrafo : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("p").item(n).getTextContent());
                }
                System.out.println("Price : "    + eElement.getElementsByTagName("price").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("Web : "    + eElement.getElementsByTagName("web").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("Imagen: "    + eElement.getElementsByTagName("image").item(0).getTextContent());

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas crear en ese for los vehiculos y ahi asignar los valores:

```
    List<Vehiculo> vehiculos=new Arraylist<Vehiculo>();
    for(int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++){
        Node node = nList.item(temp);
         System.out.println("");
         if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                    Element eElement = (Element) node;
                    System.out.println("id : "    + eElement.getAttribute("id"));
                    System.out.println("Name : "  + eElement.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getTextContent());
                    for(int n=0; n<eElement.getElementsByTagName("p").getLength(); n++) {
                        System.out.println("Parrafo : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("p").item(n).getTextContent());
                    }
                    System.out.println("Price : "    + eElement.getElementsByTagName("price").item(0).getTextContent());
                    System.out.println("Web : "    + eElement.getElementsByTagName("web").item(0).getTextContent());
                    System.out.println("Imagen: "    + eElement.getElementsByTagName("image").item(0).getTextContent());



             Vehiculo vehiculo=new Vehiculo();
             vehiculo.setPrecio(Double.parseDouble(eElement.getElementsByTagName("price").item(0).getTextContent())); 
             vehiculo.setWeb(eElement.getElementsByTagName("web").item(0).getTextContent());
             //Asi con los demas atributos 
             vehiculos.add(vehiculo);

        }
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias! @abrahamhs
He probado lo que propones pero es como si siempre sobreescribiera el mismo objeto, una vez acaba el bucle, pongo un `System.out.println(vehiculos.size());`  y siempre printa 1... :/
Además intento printar la colección con un for y no devuelve nada:

    for(int i=0; i < vehiculos.size();i++){
                        System.out.println(vehiculos.get(i));
                    }

Te copio aquí todo el codigo en la siguiente respuesta en esta cadena por su pudieras echarme una mano...

Answer (score 0):

muchas gracias! @abrahamhs
He probado lo que propones pero es como si siempre sobreescribiera el mismo objeto, una vez acaba el bucle, pongo un `System.out.println(vehiculos.size());`  y siempre printa 1... :/
Además intento printar la colección con un for y no devuelve nada:

```
for(int i=0; i < vehiculos.size();i++){
                    System.out.println(vehiculos.get(i));
                }
```

Te copio aquí todo el codigo por su pudieras echarme una mano...

```
package com.company;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;


public class Main {


    // private final static String filename = "/Users/manuelmoreno/Desktop/LA SALLE DAW/Docs y entregas/M03-UF5/UF5-PR01-VehicuosRecreativos/catalogo/mercedes.xml";


    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, TransformerException, IOException {

        File dir = new File("/Users/manuelmoreno/Desktop/LA SALLE DAW/Docs y entregas/M03-UF5/UF5-PR01-VehicuosRecreativos/catalogo");
        String[] ficheros = dir.list();

        for(int i=0; i<ficheros.length; i++) {
           // System.out.println(ficheros[i]);
            System.out.println("\n");
            Path path = Paths.get(("/Users/manuelmoreno/Desktop/LA SALLE DAW/Docs y entregas/M03-UF5/UF5-PR01-VehicuosRecreativos/catalogo/")+(ficheros[i]));
            //writeInFile(path);
            readFromFile(path);

        }

    }

    private static void readFromFile(Path path) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document document = builder.parse(path.toFile());

        //Normalize the XML Structure; It's just too important !!
        document.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        //Get all data from xml
        NodeList nList = document.getElementsByTagName("camper");

        List<Vehiculo> vehiculos = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++){
            Node node = nList.item(temp);
            System.out.println("");
            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
            {
                //Print each vehicle's detail in console and assign it to an attribute as value on vehicle objects inside "List<Vehiculo>vehiculos"

                Element eElement = (Element) node;

                System.out.println("id : "    + eElement.getAttribute("id"));
                System.out.println("Name : "  + eElement.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getTextContent());
                for(int n=0; n<eElement.getElementsByTagName("p").getLength(); n++) {
                    System.out.println("Parrafo : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("p").item(n).getTextContent());
                }
                System.out.println("Price : "    + eElement.getElementsByTagName("price").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("Web : "    + eElement.getElementsByTagName("web").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("Imagen: "    + eElement.getElementsByTagName("image").item(0).getTextContent());


                Vehiculo vehiculo = new Vehiculo();
                vehiculo.setPrecio(Double.parseDouble(eElement.getElementsByTagName("price").item(0).getTextContent()));
                vehiculo.setWeb(eElement.getElementsByTagName("web").item(0).getTextContent());
                vehiculo.setId(eElement.getAttribute("id"));
                vehiculo.setNombre(eElement.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getTextContent());
                for(int n=0; n<eElement.getElementsByTagName("p").getLength(); n++) {
                    vehiculo.setParrafos(eElement.getElementsByTagName("p").item(n).getTextContent());
                }
                // vehiculo.setImagen(eElement.getElementsByTagName("image").item(0).getTextContent());
                vehiculo.setUpdatable(eElement.getAttribute("updatable"));


                vehiculos.add(vehiculo);

                System.out.println("\n");
                System.out.println(vehiculos.size());
                // ALWAYS PRINTS 1 ....

                for(int i=0; i < vehiculos.size();i++){
                    System.out.println(vehiculos.get(i));
                }
                // DOESN'T PRINT ANYTHING.... :(
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Por cierto, dos cosas:

1- No puedo poner booleans en el bucle, así que he tenido que cambiar el tipo de dato en la clase...aunque sigo necesitando tener el dato como boolean para saber si los objetos vehículo son updatables o no, tienes alguna idea de como puedo hacerlo?

2- En el caso de la imagen, estaba usando un tipo de dato ImageIO, pero tampoco me deja ponerlo en el bucle de creación del arraylist. Tienes algún consejo de como solucionarlo?

MIL GRACIAS!!!!

Comment: Estas equivocado, el for que pones para imprimir `vehiculos` debe ir fuera del for de `temp`, si lo pones dentro siempre te va a pintar uno y se sobreescribe. El booleano si se debe de poder parsear con una conversión pero de la imagen no te puedo decir ya que no conozco el xml.